# Story (or series) with AI copies of people with 'alpha' or 'beta' quality, artifact searching

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book a while back and was curious to finish it, but lost it. Story elements I recall:

- characters can copy/replicate themselves (or at least their minds) and there are two 'grades' of the copies

  - alpha: basically the same as the person, regulated?
  - beta: good for doing lesser work in your style, like editing a paper or something
- one of the main characters had an alpha-copy of their deceased father (or other relative) to talk to(?)
- ancient artifact hunting or some other 'dig', impeded by storms (sand or snow?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Revelation Space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_Space) by Alastair Reynolds

[Beta simulation](https://revelationspace.fandom.com/wiki/Beta-level_simulation#:%7E:text=Beta%2Dlevel%20simulations%20were%20sophisticated,near%2Dperfect%20imitations%20of%20life.)

**characters can copy/replicate themselves (or at least their minds) and there are two 'grades' of the copies**

> Beta-level simulations were sophisticated computer programs designed
> to mimic a person in appearance, mannerisms, and thought-patterns.
> While capable of successfully impersonating a human mind down to their
> most minute idiosyncrasies, they were not in fact self-aware -- they
> were just near-perfect imitations of life. As such, they enjoyed no
> legal rights or protection

**one of the main characters had an alpha-copy of their deceased father (or other relative) to talk to(?)**

[Dan Sylveste](https://revelationspace.fandom.com/wiki/Dan_Sylveste)

> Sometime after arriving on Resurgam Dan's eye were injured, and replaced with prosthetic ones by the beta-level simulation of his
> father, Calvin.

**ancient artifact hunting or some other 'dig', impeded by storms (sand or snow?)**

[Detailed Summary of Revelation Space](https://revelationspace.fandom.com/wiki/Revelation_Space)

> As a violent dust storm threatens to temporarily
> shut down the excavation, Sylveste discovers new evidence that the
> entire Amarantin race achieved a much higher level of technological
> sophistication than was previously known, before they were wiped out
> in a single mysterious cataclysm.

Comment: whilst this particular case is undoubtedly Revelation Space itself, the alpha, beta, (and gamma) AI's are also in many of his other works in the same universe